# Access Mac OSX file tags with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, tags, finder

Mac OS X Mavericks introduced a built-in tagging system in Finder.

Is it possible to access a file's tags with Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

This gem might do the trick: [ffi-xattr](https://github.com/jarib/ffi-xattr)